# If array location is populated from variable, do subsequent comparisons result in the comparison with the variable name or variable contents

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm sure the answer to this is out there but I'm struggling with the terminology to describe exactly what I mean. I'm looping over a game map with lots of SVGs inside individual DIVs and I want to know if Javascript is comparing the two 9 character strings **svgString** and **svgString** (seems like a short and simple comparison), or is it comparing the thousands of characters in my variable to the thousands of characters in my array (seems like a long comparison and I will perhaps look for a different solution)?

This [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m0qpvned/) shows an example of what I mean. If I was doing this regularly, and for perhaps 500 different different game cells in a row, I feel like 500 X 14 character comparisons is bearable. But millions of character comparisons feels like it might be a little slow.

Code duplicated below and I've used a more simple SVG in both code and Fiddle for simplicity.

```
<div id="rocket">

</div>
<div id="clicker" onclick="numCheck()">
  Click Me (if you want)
</div>
```

```
#rocket {
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
  background: red;
}
#rocket svg {
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
}
#clicker {
  width: 256px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```
let svgString = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">\
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"\
     width="256px" height="256px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" enable-background="new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve">\
<g>\
    <g>\
        <g>\
            <path fill="#020202" d="M204.192,62.194c14.147-20.472,29.339-41.613,50.963-54.72c21.323,12.782,36.366,33.547,50.311,53.656\
                c32.847,49.754,52.929,109.515,48.878,169.578c10.615,8.898,21.537,17.441,31.994,26.521\
                c15.011,13.797,22.02,35.319,18.406,55.327c-5.036,25.275-9.876,50.607-15.206,75.813c-2.963,12.968-20.508,18.905-30.823,10.62\
                c-17.121-14.291-33.816-29.108-50.932-43.417c-12.95,12.462-30.153,20.772-48.214,21.773\
                c-20.791,1.466-41.375-7.156-56.448-21.242c-12.28,9.401-23.666,20.686-35.664,30.755c-5.799,4.66-10.621,10.784-17.484,13.966\
                c-10.64,4.565-24.342-2.248-26.747-13.685c-5.479-24.642-11.203-49.24-16.52-73.92c-4.321-20.878,3.332-43.61,19.419-57.607\
                c9.313-7.822,18.756-15.487,28.243-23.096c2.643-1.39,1.315-4.596,1.465-6.951C153.005,167.614,172.8,110.333,204.192,62.194z\
                 M220.995,138.526c-12.424,15.994-10.921,40.768,3.488,55.052c15.255,16.809,44.15,17.422,60.106,1.29\
                c12.317-11.253,16.482-30.146,10.603-45.671c-5.387-14.967-19.809-26.195-35.671-27.591\
                C244.873,119.92,229.706,126.659,220.995,138.526z"/>\
        </g>\
        <path fill="#020202" d="M198.263,407.819c-0.213-7.266,8.83-12.262,14.942-8.417c25.87,13.32,58.027,13.314,83.896-0.007\
            c5.937-3.645,14.736,0.733,14.955,7.803c0.087,15.432,0.105,30.88,0.024,46.317c0.119,7.533-9.832,12.337-15.681,7.626\
            c-4.452-3.926-8.467-8.341-12.75-12.461c-6.776,13.201-13.163,26.602-19.995,39.772c-3.281,6.275-13.533,6.318-16.877,0.105\
            c-6.87-13.195-13.213-26.676-20.121-39.858c-4.221,4.157-8.248,8.548-12.694,12.468c-5.824,4.734-15.756-0.162-15.675-7.647\
            C198.163,438.291,198.244,423.055,198.263,407.819z"/>\
    </g>\
    <circle fill="#020202" cx="254.831" cy="164.509" r="20.812"/>\
</g>\
</svg>'

let array1 = [svgString, svgString, svgString, svgString, svgString];

function numCheck() {
  if (array1[2] === svgString) {
    document.getElementById('rocket').innerHTML = array1[2];
  } else {
    //do nout
  }
}
```

Comment: The variable identifier are not taken into account. The strings will be compared. If you want to speed  speed up compares, consider generating a hash and comparing those. Precompute the hash, since the svg is stable.

Answer (score 0):

Values in JavaScript are references to objects (except for primitive types like numbers).

When you perform an `===` test, it first checks whether both values refer to the same object. This is a very quick test, it just compares the memory addresses in the references.

If they don't refer to the same objects, it may perform a type-specific equality check; in the case of strings, this will compare the strings character by character.

In your case, since you assigned the array elements from the same variable that you're comparing with, the array contains references to the same string objects. So the first test of object equality will succeed, and it doesn't need to compare the text in the strings (if the objects are at the same address, they obviously have the same contents).

Comment: That's great. A side question then...
If I set the innerHTML of `rocket` as shown and then I do another comparison..
```if (document.getElementById('rocket').innerHTML === array1[2]) {...```
does the innerHTML which I set from the object also refer to the same memory location?

Comment: That needs to create a new string from the DOM hierarchy, so it will have to compare the contents.

Comment: The DOM doesn't contain the raw string. When you assigned to `innerHTML` it parsed the HTML into a hierarchy of objects. When you read `innerHTML`, it has to walk all the DOM elements and create a new string representation.

Comment: Thankyou. I will try and keep all comparisons to variables and array locations which point to the same object then.